# Exception at removing Row Datagrid view

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

My grid view has some items I can remove each sucessfully by just writing

```
ViewActiveJobs.Rows.RemoveAt(SelectedRow);
```

but this dosent help when deleting last(only one row remaning) item in grid view .I have used drop down list for this job that has many options from which i can select delete item to delete row but an exception is encountered Deleting last entery

Exceptions occurs at program.cs my form dost not returns any value to program .cs and  program .cs has

```
Application.Run(new MainView(LoggedUserName,LoggedUserType));
```

to run a MDI parent and its child has datagrid view that should be able to delete items

Exception is 
Index -1 does not have a value.

But if i remove removeAt line its fine what happens is record gets deleted at database but not frontend

Comment: and what is the exception? where is stack trace?

Comment: Does the last row have data or is this the default row which shows up when enabling AllowUserToAddRows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridView control is very quirky, and you're better off using a third-party grid control.  But, if you're encountering a problem similar to what I've encountered in the past, simply setting the grid view to invisible while performing the final record deletion might do the trick, since the control runs into trouble when it tries to refresh its display when its data becomes "lost."  But, it depends really on what the exception is.

Comment: Your latest edit to your question notes that the Exception is "Index -1 does not have a value." A stack trace would be helpful, here. But, this does sound similar to what I've encountered in the past in some cases. To clarify what I suggested, before performing the deletion, set the Grid View's Visible property to false, delete the record, and then set the Visible property back to true. If you are still encountering the issue afterward you can also try disconnecting the data source from the grid (while invisible) and removing the record from the data source, instead, and then reconnect to grid